# Add legend in a Graphic inside a Manipulate

Tags: plotting, graphics, gui-construction

I use this manipulate:

```
Manipulate[spos=0.08;pntx2=First[pt2]; pnty2=Last[pt2];
        Graphics[{{Red, Circle[]},
        {Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, pt2}]},
        {Text["K",{0 + spos,pnty2+spos}]},
        {Text["0",{0 - spos, 0 - spos}]},
        {Point[{{0,pnty2}}]},
        {Dashed, Line[{{0,pnty2}, pt2},VertexColors->{Black, Black}]},
        {Thickness[spes], Line[{{0,0},{0,pnty2}},VertexColors->{Blue, Blue}]}},
        Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2],
        {{pt2, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction ->((pt2 = Normalize[#]) &)},ContentSize->{300,300}]
```

How can I insert a legend similar to `PlotLegends` with a color line and a label for each line in the graphic?

`PlotLegends` is not available in that context.

Comment: Is this question different than: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147017/5478?

Comment: @Kuba it is a duplicate, sorry

Comment: Now the web page is not found.